# having a div slide down into view vertically

Tags: jquery, css

I have two objectives from this post; one to have a tool-tips div slide down as if it were "under" the top of the parent, and secondly, ideally, to have this work regardless of the tool-tip's height - i.e. bottom of tool-tip always lined up with top edge of parent div.

http://jsfiddle.net/sfullman/y1on62pd/

The html is as follows:

```
<div class="container1">
    state 1<br>this is the main content
    <div id="i1" class="tooltip">this is the tool section</div>
</div>
<div class="container1">
    state 2<br>this is the main content
    <div id="i2" class="tooltip">this is the tool section slid down</div>
</div>
```

and the css as follows:

```
body{
    font-family:Arial;
}
.container1{
    box-sizing:border-box;
    border:1px solid black;
    width:450px;
    min-height:300px;
    position:relative;
    padding:10px;
    margin:25px auto;
}
.tooltip{
    position:absolute;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    right:50px;
    width:150px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid gray;
    padding:10px;
}
#i1{
    top:-100px;
}
#i2{
    top:0px;
}
```

Comment: so what have you tried? SO isn't a code writing service. You have to at least attempt this on your own.

Comment: ok so if i understand you want us to do the JOB right?

Comment: I'm sorry. This question is missing a "question"...

Comment: you're right, my question would be "how to do this in the best way" and also "how to position the bottom edge of child to top edge of parent" - I did figure out a way for the first, but still unknown about the second.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're going to want to use CSS transitions.

```
-moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;  
-o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out; 
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out; 
transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
```

I also added a tooltip container class to handle your styling and allow the tooltip to be a height of 0.

This should work for you:
http://jsfiddle.net/3z3s7tLf/

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this that's pretty simple using overflow:hidden.  Probably overflow-y would be better so that wide elements would still cause a scrollbar.

http://jsfiddle.net/sfullman/y1on62pd/1/

One question still remains as to how to position the BOTTOM edge of the tool-tip div with the TOP edge of the parent, if the tool-tip div has an indefinite height.  I'm posting the CSS here as it's most relevant and different from my original:

```
body{
    font-family:Arial;
}
.container1{
    box-sizing:border-box;
    border:1px solid black;
    width:450px;
    min-height:300px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:10px;
    margin:25px auto;
}
.tooltip{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    right:50px;
    width:150px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid gray;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
}
#i1{
    top:-100px;
}
#i2{
    top:0px;
}
```